# SQL query is saying too many columns in sub query

Tags: sql

I have two tables: a candidate table with candidate ID as a main key and the second table is one of educations linking candidate ID with the school they went to.

I want to filter schools where there are 50 or more candidates from that school. I also want the candidate names too.

```
select candidates.first_name, candidates.last_name
from candidates
where candidates.id IN (select e.candidate_id, e.school_name, count(e.school_name)
                        from educations e
                        group by e.candidate_id, e.school_name
                        having count(e.school_name) >= 50)
```

I'm getting an error that says:

> Subquery has too many columns

Comment: That's not how you use `in` - you need to use `exists`

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a subquery inside an `IN` condition, your subquery can only return a single column.

Comment: your query makes no sense

Comment: You're welcome to elaborate. While this is not the best solution, it is the closest to what the OP was trying to do. There are certainly alternatives that could be provided, however the above query will return the first/last name of the candidates for schools with 50+ candidates.

Comment: candidates has no school_name column, so your query will not run. it only explains how in works.

Answer (score 0):

As Stu already said in the coment, a `EXISTS` would be faster than an `IN` clause

In ana `IN` your subselect only can return so many columns as a defined by the column name(s) before the `IN`

This example of a query is for MySQL, but it should work on any Databse system
and of course is simplified

```
CREATE tABLE candidates (id int, first_name varchar(10), last_name varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO candidates VALUEs(1,'a','an'),(2,'b','bn')
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
create TablE educations (id int, candidate_id int,school_name varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO educations VALUES (1,1,'school A'),(2,1,'school B'),(3,1,'school C'),(4,1,'school D')
  ,(5,1,'school E'),(6,2,'school A'),(7,2,'school B'),(9,2,'school C')
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
select candidates.first_name, candidates.last_name
from candidates
where EXISTS (select 1
                        from educations e
                        WHERE e.candidate_id = candidates.id 
                        having count(e.school_name) >= 5)
```

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| a | an |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xAGEg3AF)